# Spawning more threads than you have in a gevent pool

Tags: pool, gevent, spawn

As I understand it the idea of a pool in gevent is to limit the total number of concurrent requests at any time, to a database or an API or similar.

Say I have code like this where I am spawning more greenlets than I have room for in the `Pool`:

```
import gevent.pool

pool = gevent.pool.Pool(50)
jobs = []
for number in xrange(300):
    jobs.append(pool.spawn(do_something, number))

total_result = [x.get() for x in jobs]
```

What is the actual behavior when trying to spawn the 51st request? When is the 51st request handled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pool class uses a semaphore to count active greenlets, initialized with `size` count in the constructor:

```
class Pool(Group):

    def __init__(self, size=None, greenlet_class=None):
        if size is not None and size < 1:
            raise ValueError('Invalid size for pool (positive integer or None required): %r' % (size, ))
        Group.__init__(self)
        self.size = size
        if greenlet_class is not None:
            self.greenlet_class = greenlet_class
        if size is None:
            self._semaphore = DummySemaphore()
        else:
            self._semaphore = Semaphore(size)
```

Every time `spawn()` is called, it tries to acquire the semaphore:

```
    def spawn(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._semaphore.acquire()
        try:
            greenlet = self.greenlet_class.spawn(*args, **kwargs)
            self.add(greenlet)
        except:
            self._semaphore.release()
            raise
        return greenlet
```

If the pool is full, the called greenlet will thus wait on `_semaphore.acquire()` call. Semaphore is released whenever any of the greenlets ends execution:

```
    def discard(self, greenlet):
       Group.discard(self, greenlet)
       self._semaphore.release()
```

So in your case, I'd expect the 51st request to be handled (or started, to be precise) as soon as any of the first 50 requests is done.